# Regex string extraction from txt file separated by comma

Tags: python, regex

I have a **txt file** that has the following format.

```
name:,john smith,
age:,23 
birth date:,/  / 
variable1,foo,1,bar
variable2,foo,2,bar
variable3,foo,5,bar
variable4,foo,19,bar
```

As you may have noticed, the first 3 lines has the format either `<string>:,` or `<string>:, ,`.
In the remaining lines, string and values are **separated by 3 commas**

I have been trying to apply regex such as this code: `re.findall('(.*?)\,(.*)',text)`
But since I have very limited understanding of regex expressions, I cannot figure out how to extract all the data from the txt file.

The reason why I want to extract all data through regex is to pivot the values data into a single row where variable names make up the columns as such:

```
name        age   birth date  variable1_foo variable2_foo variable3_foo variable4_foo
johnsmith    34   /   /         1                  2             5            19
```

Any solutions? Much help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: i just edited the final desired dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want what ever up to the first colon or comma as key and the rest as a value...

```
^([^,:]+)[,:]*+(.*)$
```

I put some online example here. https://rubular.com/r/YLlHaXNKvEHHaN

How ever your example you provide in the question is very counter intuitive... You don't mention e.g. - if a key is followed by ,foo it is transformed to _foo and if a value is followed by ,bar it is ignored.

Regex don't go like this: I want a regex that does something I have forgotten to specify put it must be a regex...

Answer (score 0):

You might use 2 capture groups to get the values shown in the desired result, and replace the `,` with `_` for the second group if you want.

In the demo I have added `\n` to the negated character class to prevent crossing newlines in the example.

```
^(.+?(?=:,)|[^,]+,[^,]+):?,([^,]+)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `.+?(?=:,)` Match 1+ times as least as possible chars until you can assert `:,` directly to the right
  - `|` Or
  - `[^,]+,[^,]+` Match 1+ times any char except `,` then match the `,` and again match 1+ times any char except`,`
- `):?` Close group 1 and match optional `:`
- `,` Match literally
- `([^,]+)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ times any char except `,`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H2DsGh/1)

As an example, you can collect all the values from the groups and perform a replacement on group 2.

```
# data = read the whole file here
pattern = r"^(.+?(?=:,)|[^,\n]+,[^,\n]+):?,([^,\n]+)"
group1 = []
group2 = []

matches = re.finditer(pattern, data, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    group1.append(match.group(1).replace(",", "_"))
    group2.append(match.group(2).replace(" ", ""))

df = pd.DataFrame([group1, group2])
print(df.to_string(index=False, header=False))
```

Output

```
     name age birth date variable1_foo variable2_foo variable3_foo variable4_foo
johnsmith  23         //             1             2             5            19
```

Note that John has aged from 23 to 34.